# Read JSON file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, save

I am trying to read JSON file like this:

> `[166.1086159,153.6025535,109.9585098,149.0443019,121.9854975,136.2424609,68.07276721,75.02149785,112.0627478]`

I deleted most of the numbers inside. I have around 200 of json files like that(depending on which button you press), so the question is how do I save this array to a variable? 
I've been banging my head about this for quite some time!

All help appreciated!

> ```
> <!doctype html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>       <title>Bar Chart</title>
>       <script src="./Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>       <div style="width: 80%">
>           <canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="800"></canvas>
>       </div>
>
>
>
> <script>
> function reqListener () {
>     console.log(this.responseText);
>     current = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
> }
> ```

```
>   var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
>    oReq.onload = reqListener;
>    oReq.open("get", file, true);
>    oReq.send();
```

> ```
>   var barChartData = {
>       labels : ["501", "502", "503", "504", "505", "506", "507", "508", "509", "510",
>               "511", "512", "513", "514", "515", "516", "517", "518", "519", "520",
>               "521", "522", "523", "524", "525", "526", "527", "528", "529", "530",
>               "531", "532", "533", "534", "535", "536", "537", "538", "539", "540",
>               "541", "542", "543", "544", "545", "546", "547", "548", "549", "550",
>               "551", "552", "553", "554", "555", "556", "557", "558", "559", "560",
>               "561", "562", "563", "564", "565", "566", "567", "568", "569", "570",
>               "571", "572", "573", "574", "575", "576", "577", "578", "579", "580",],
>       datasets : [
>           {
>               fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
>               strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
>               highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
>               highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
>               data : current
>           }
>       ]
>
>   }
>   window.onload = function(){
>       var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
>       window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
>           responsive : true
>       });
>   }
>
>   </script>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: What does your JavaScript code look like? Please provide it in your question.

Comment: json **IS** javascript. `var foo = [166....];` and off you go - one standard javascript array.

Comment: I edited and added JS code. @MarcB I know that, but I have over 200 of json and I only need one at the time, dont want to put them in the JS file aswell - too much work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the file contents into a string variable, you use:

```js
var string = '[166.1086159,153.6025535,109.9585098,149.0443019,121.9854975,136.2424609,68.07276721,75.02149785,112.0627478]';
var array = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(array);
```

If the data is in a file on your server, you can use AJAX to read it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest for examples of how to use the `XMLHttpRequest` interface in Javascript for this.

Comment: What should I put where is says string? pathname?

Comment: `string` is the variable that contains the contents of the file that you read, e.g. with `XMLHttpRequest` (AJAX).

Comment: Thank you for that, I got the array as string, but for some reason I get an error in JSON.parse: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: That error means the string is not properly formatted as JSON. Without seeing how you're setting the string, I can't explain any better. You need to show that code in your question.

Comment: The funny part is that in Mozilla (firebug) I get the responseText like this: `"[166.1086159,153.6025535,109.9585098,149.0443019,121.9854975,136.2424609,68.07276721,75.02149785,112.0627478]"`, but in IE I get Access is Denied, when trying to read.
Error here: [link](http://i.imgur.com/ph9jZyE.png)

Comment: access denied might be an AJAX same-origin issue.

Comment: Could be the problem that I don't have a server running? How can I solve this problem?
I edited my current code

Comment: That could be. I think browser differ in whether they allow AJAX to local files.

Answer (score 1):

Just use JSON.parse and pass in the file text as a string and then save it to a variable

```
var fileText = '';//load the file text

var jsonData = JSON.parse(fileText);
```

Comment: I already tried that, but for some reason it gives me an error: 
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: How are you loading the file text?

Comment: I edited and added the JS code aswell, what do you mean with the loading the file text?

Comment: Just saw your html, don't really get what you're trying to do

Comment: My json file is in the same folder as this code. Well I'm trying to create a bar chart, but depending which json I choose that will be the result. I just want to read the json in an array.

Comment: Okay so you're loading the file on the click of a button, but how?

Comment: I don't have that implemented yet. But when I would click tempo that it would load tempo json into current, is that possible?
Like the way you posted, but it doesnt work.

Comment: If the JSON file looks exactly like you posted, then you shouldn't have a problem loading it and then parsing it using JSON.parse, unless I'm missing something

Comment: Yes, this is what I don't understand. The Json is exactly as posted, but it gives me SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character.
I puted it in the <script> tag as
`var fileText = './tempo/tempo.json';
var temp = JSON.parse(fileText);`
and it doesnt work

Comment: why are you putting the fie name in the variable?

Comment: @Kladnik You can't just put a filename there, you have to write Javascript code to read the file into a variable. Read about AJAX.

Comment: I figured out that yes, but for some reason it still doesnt work, I have the following code: `$.getJSON(file, function(json){
  current = json;`
 });